# Evaluate JSON object with expression with variable name, Josson Evaluate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, extjs

We need to evaluate JSON object expressions in java.

We have the following source JSON object

```
{
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300,
  "d": "calc(a+c)",
  "f": {
    "g": 100,
    "h": 200,
    "i": "calc(g+h)",
    "k": {
      "m": 50,
      "n": 70,
      "p": "calc(m+n)"
    }
  }
}
```

we need to output this format

```
{
  "a": 100,
  "b": 200,
  "c": 300,
  "d": 400,
  "f": {
    "g": 100,
    "h": 200,
    "i": 300,
    "k": {
      "m": 50,
      "n": 70,
      "p": 120
    }
  }
}
```

we know the json structure. But can you suggest more generic way where the json structure is not known and json can be iterated and eval can be done wherever some formuala like calc, concat is used. Also maintain the depth of json.